# Unable to create custom Web part properties for custom content search web part in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, custom-web-part-property, cswp

I tried to create custom web properties for custom content search web part [Extended CSWP](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/799307/Extend-Content-Search-web-part-to-add-Target-Audie)by using

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
 WebDisplayName("Page Title"),
 WebDescription("Title displayed on the page"),
 Category("Test Properties"),
 Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public string PageTitle
{
    get
    {
        return PageTitle;
    }
    set
    {
        PageTitle = value;
    }
}
```

It's not created the custom web part property, Any help?